# How to make the assumption of the second case of an Isabelle/Isar proof by cases explicit right in place?

Tags: proof, isabelle, isar

I have an Isabelle proof structured as follows:

```
proof (cases "n = 0")
  case True
  (* lots of stuff here *)
  show ?thesis sorry
next
  case False
  (* lots of stuff here too *)
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

The first case is actually several pages long, so when reading the second case it's no longer clear to a casual reader, not even to myself, what the `False` refers to.  (Well, it actually *is*, but not from reading, only in an interactive environment: If, e.g., in Isabelle/jEdit, you place the cursor after `case False`, you'll see `n ≠ 0` under "this" in the Output panel.)

So is there a syntax that allows for making the assumption of the "False" case explicit, so that the reader neither has to interact with the IDE, nor to scroll up to the `proof` keyword, but can see the assumption right in place?

Comment: Reopened! Let's start over with the comments, shall we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the proof becomes more readable by stating the assumption of each case explicitly:

```
proof cases
  assume "n = 0"
  show ?thesis sorry
next
  assume "n ≠ 0"
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

Comment: NB: This fails if you re-order the cases (as pointed out by @LarsNoschinsiki in a comment to my answer).

Answer (score 5):

If the `False` case is shorter, just put it first. The order of proofs in an Isar block does not matter:

```
proof (cases "n = 0")
  case False
  show ?thesis sorry
next
  case True
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

Comment: In general, if the property on which we do case analysis is very short (like in `n = 0`), I would always prefer the explicit version instead of `case False`, `case True`, for readability. (Funnily, from a compositionality viewpoint the opposite is true.)

Comment: Note that you can only reorder the cases if you call the `cases` method with a parameter. If you use the form `proof cases assume P ... next assume "~P" ...` then the negated case must be the second (as there are schematics in the goal which are instantiated by the first `show` command).

Comment: I did not not even know that you can use `cases` without an parameter :-)

Answer (score 2):

Isar allows many variations on the same theme.  Keeping the original outline, you can make intermediate facts explicit like this:

```
proof (cases "n = 0")
  case True
  (* lots of stuff here *)
  from `n = 0` show ?thesis sorry
next
  case False
  (* lots of stuff here too *)
  from `n ≠ 0` show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

This is a conservative extension of the original proof outline, i.e. it does not introduce any change in the policies of checking, unification, search etc.

Generally, the form

```
note `prop`
```

is equivalent to

```
have "prop" by fact
```